# FirebaseRecycleAdapter UncaughtException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseRecycleAdapter to populate comments system:

CommentViewHolder.class:

```
public class CommentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView displayNameView;
TextView bodyView;
String uid;

CommentViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    displayNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_displayName);
    bodyView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_body);
}

public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    displayNameView.setText(displayName);
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    bodyView.setText(body);
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}
}
```

And in my activity:

```
mCommentsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_comments);
mCommentsRecycler.setHasFixedSize(false);
mCommentsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentViewHolder>(Comment.class, R.layout.comment_item, CommentViewHolder.class, CommentsReference) {
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(CommentViewHolder viewHolder, final Comment model, int position) {
viewHolder.setDisplayName(model.getDisplayName());
viewHolder.setBody(model.getBody());
viewHolder.setUid(model.getUid());
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          showCommentClickedList(model);
       }
    });
 }
};
mCommentsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I tried to put the ViewHolder inside the activity with "public static" like I saw in some answers, but same error,

**And the most wired part - WHEN I RUN IT FROM ANDROID STUDIO, It works perfect, once I create debug apk or release apk the problem start to come**

The error:

```
04-10 15:13:16.137 22024-22024/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: PID: 22024
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
   at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:171)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6319)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5507)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5392)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5388)
```

`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:171)`
is `Constructor<VH> constructor = mViewHolderClass.getConstructor(View.class);`

Comment: are you using proguard? It looks like the code isn't there at run time (you're probably accidentally assigning a signingConfig when you assemble your debug, and probably release anyway)

Comment: nope, not using proguard

Comment: and is there any special config done in your build file or anywhere else?

Comment: The only diffrent in release is lintOptions - disable 'MissingTranslation

Comment: Okay, and do you just use the debug keystore for both?

Comment: Dude, there isn't connection to any of this, if debug apk and release apk infected the same so the problem isn't there I guess...

Comment: it's not matter of infection, it's configuration. Your code builds or you couldn't run it, at runtime, it can't find a function. Something is not resolving correctly

Comment: Your constructor isn't marked as `public`, so the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` can't find it.

Comment: Here we go, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ViewHolder` is declared inside your [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java), then it should be `public` and `static`.

In both cases, declaring inside [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) or on its own class, the constructor must be `public`.